# Install ssh server on embedded device

Tags: linux, ssh, embedded, arm, atmel

I'm trying to connect to an embedded device through `ssh`. However, when trying to connect, I always get a `connection refused` message even when I try changing the port number. I've tried everything to resolve this issue, from changing the file in `/etc/ssh/` to accept the specific port number, to `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT`
.

After reading some comments, it came to me that *maybe* one of the problems is that I don't have `ssh` installed on my embedded device. So, how do I infact install ssh on an embedded device? I'm working with a FOX G20 V board with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20.

I would appreciate any help since I've been stuck on this problem for several days now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cross compile OpenSSH for your embedded device,Follow below steps

1. Download OpenSSH from 
   http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz
2. extract it and cross-compile it using toolchain

   ./configure --host="board architecture"

   make
3. Copy sshd from compiled source and download it in your embedded
   device and run it

   /path/sshd
4. Try to connect with your embedded device

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once I get the compiled source, how exactly do I download it to my embedded device and run it? And what do you mean by "/path/sshd"? Thanks.

Comment: If you have serial port access of embedded device then you can download sshd into your board using tftp, /path/sshd/ mean you have to run sshd from path where you have downloaded it

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to this but I'm using an arm embedded toolchain: `arm-none-eabi-gcc` so what exactly do I have to type in the command line argument to cross compile (once I've downloaded OpenSSH)? Also, I don't have tftp installed nor can I install it. What's another way to download the compiled source onto the embedded device? Thanks.

Comment: first set path of your toolchain in terminal then ./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc AR=arm-none-eabi-ar
 make

Comment: Do you have serial access?

Comment: What do you mean by serial access? But ok I'll type ./configure --host=arm-linux CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc AR=arm-none-eabi-ar make in the openSSH directory I presume?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51184/discussion-between-rahul-r-dhobi-and-john-smith)

Comment: @RahulRDhobi I have a similar problem . Through tftp i have copied sshd which was prebuilt for arm to /etc/sbin/. I tried to run the demon but it is showing the message "./sshd not found ". but the file is present there.
 What could be the reason??

Comment: @kernel:Don't use prebuild binary instead compile using your toolchain might be they compiled sshd using different toochain

Answer (score 4):

This may come a bit late, but may be useful for someone, but for a embedded device **you may want also to consider**:

- [WolfSSH](https://www.wolfssl.com/products/wolfssh/)
- [Dropbear](https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html)
- [mbed TLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) (formerly known as PolarSSL)

As far as I know all of them should work on ARM, **you will probably have to cross compile** as [Rahul R Dhobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184706/rahul-r-dhobi) said.